# How can I set up 'multiply if' logic?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two sheets. One with customer IDs and products bought, the other one with a price list for each product. For each customer, I want to check which products they bought then multiply by the price list number to get how much each customer spent on each product.

So the logic is: if item name in customer sheet matches item name in price list sheet, multiply customer quantity by price list to get total price. I want to do this for every customer and for each of their products. How can I do this in Excel?

Here's an example:

Customers and Products Bought

| Customer ID | Product | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apples | 3 |
| 1 | Oranges | 2 |
| 2 | Apples | 7 |
| 2 | Oranges | 5 |

Price List

| Product | Price/Unit |
| --- | --- |
| Apples | $1 |
| Oranges | $1.50 |

In this case, Customer 1 spent $3 on apples and $3 on oranges. Customer 2 spent $7 on apples and $7.50 on oranges. I want to add another column named total price to the customer table showing this information.

Comment: `=PRODUCT(IF(A1:A4="bob",B1:B4,""))`  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/product-function-8e6b5b24-90ee-4650-aeec-80982a0512ce

Comment: Hi @Gantendo , thanks for this. How would it work? It checks for who the customer is and what they bought but does not multiply.

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner , thanks for this. Would that formula work the same if I have over 200 customers who each bought a minimum of 50 products?

Comment: Yes, it just looks up the value for the product and multiplies it by the quantity, line by line. See my answer below

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks

Answer (score 2):

simply VLOOKUP to get the price:

```
=C2*VLOOKUP(B2,F:G,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it is not big of a data, VLOOKUP mentioned above and pivot can do the trick

=C2*VLOOKUP(B2,F:G,2,FALSE) in column D as mentioned above would give you total spend of a customer for a particular fruit.
Then Pivot on sheet from Column A:D would do. In pivot, drag Customer ID to row and total to aggregate (select sum in bottom left if it shows count in pivot)